# Cannot link libraries to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen some similar questions on this forum but none of them worked for me so I am going to ask it here.

So I have a custom package that generates a library file (ATC3DGlib64.so) during compilation and stores it in `/usr/lib64/`. This custom package is compiled using a makefile and I am trying to put this package in my ROS workspace.

Below are the actual two command that are executed from the makefile when I run

```
make -f makefile
```

and I want to put all these commands in a CMakeLists.txt

```
g++ -DLINUX -I/opt/3DGuidance.Rev.E.64/3DGuidanceAPI -fPIC -pthread -m64 -c GetSynchronousRecordSample.cpp

g++ -m64 GetSynchronousRecordSample.o /usr/lib64/ATC3DGlib64.so -o GetSynchronousRecord64
```

Essentially there is one .cpp file that needs to compiled and linked to the library file that is in the `/usr/lib64/`.

I have tried to link the ATC3DGlib64.so file to my executable in the CMakeLists.txt in many ways but none of them have worked for me. I keep getting this error when I run `catkin_make`

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lATC3DGlib64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From what I read online it seems these kind of errors generate when the path is wrong and/or name is wrong and/or the library is not installed. I doubt any of these are true in my case.

I have also tried to create a **symbolic link** between the original library file that is in `/usr/lib64/` to my `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/` folder by running

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/ATC3DGlib64.so ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/
```

For `code reference` I am attaching the `makefile` ([C:\fakepath\makefile.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15876049245749188.png)) and `my CMakeLists.txt` in parts (PART1:[C:\fakepath\cmake_1.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1587605171859069.png), PART2:[C:\fakepath\cmake_2.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15876051887490709.png), PART3:[C:\fakepath\cmake_3.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1587605207162656.png), PART4:[C:\fakepath\cmake_4.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15876052231313607.png)).

If anyone knows whats going on or has suggestions on what to try then please reply.
Thanks for reading!

---

Some useful links that have unfortunately not worked for me but might be useful to others.

1. [LINK](https://answers.ros.org/question/189950/how-to-use-so-file-in-ros/) mentioning how to add .so file to CMakeLists.txt. Has a usueful link to [ROS Wiki Using thrid party libs](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingThirdPartyLibraries) too!
2. Add target link dependences, for ATC3DG.ini file - [StackOverflow LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864689/cmake-how-to-add-dependency-on-linker-script-for-executable)

I will add some more relevant links here soon...

**UPDATE:**
[THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085079/import-an-external-library-into-a-ros-node) solved my problem. I am able to build the package now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350312/cannot-link-libraries-to-cmakelists.txt/) by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-23**:
Quick comment: this seems like a CMake problem. Not a ROS one.

**Comment by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on 2020-04-23**:
Could be, could be not. I am not sure at the moment.

**Comment by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on 2020-04-23**:
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085079/import-an-external-library-into-a-ros-node) solved my problem. I am able to build the package now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-23**:
So this was a CMake issue.

Please post your last edit as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085079/import-an-external-library-into-a-ros-node) solved my problem. I am able to build the package now.

---

Originally posted by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) with karma: 51 on 2020-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0